# Idiomatic Python for non-trivial list comprehensions

Tags: python, idioms

Performing a simple transformation over an iterable in Python is idiomatically achieved with a list comprehension:

```
y = [f(arg) for arg in args]
```

where `f` is a [simple statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html), or a functional `map` if `f` is a named function:

```
y = map(f, args)
```

Guido [favors list comprehensions](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html) over `map(lambda x:..., args)`, and indeed list comprehensions over usage of `map` or `filter` [at all](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

However, it's not clear to me how I should approach problems that:

- modify each element in an iterable,
- in a non-trivial manner,
- using a discrete piece of logic (could be a function),
- that isn't useful anywhere else

What is the most idiomatic way of solving this type of problem?
Some things I've seen and tried across the Python projects I've worked on:

### Predeclare and loop

The obvious way is to predeclare the output and loop:

```
def transform(...):

    ...

    y = []
    for arg in args:
        first_statement
        second_statement
        ...
        y.append(statement)
```

Comments:

- (pro) easy to follow the logic
- (con) logic not scoped (leaking abstraction)
- (con) logic not explicit (how do you know it's a map without checking how all branches in the loop operate?)
- (con) unnecessarily predeclares variable in a non-useful manner (`y` MUST be the same length as `args`)

### Nested Function

Another option is to encapsulate the logic in a nested function, then invoke it using a map or list comprehension:

```
def transform(...):

    ...

    def anonymous(arg):
        first_statement
        second_statement
        ...
        return statement

    y = map(anonymous, args)
    # y = [anonymous(arg) for arg in args]
```

Comments:

- (Pro) Encapsulates logic
- (Pro) Can access outer scope
- (Pro) Cannot modify outer scope (explicit about having no side-effects)
- (Con) Inner function is redefined every time it is called
- (Con) Inner function has no real name (should be anonymous in the scope of the map)

### Outer Function

Moving the inner function to the outer scope solves some of these problems, but introduces more:

```
def _anonymous(arg):
    first_statement
    second_statement
    ...
    return statement

def transform(...):

    ...

    y = map(_anonymous, args)
```

Comments:

- (Pro): function is compiled once at parse-time
- (Con): function is too far from call-site for a small piece of logic (induces unnecessary context-switch for programmer)
- (Con): function has no access to outer scope. Any requirements must be passed in (preventing use of `map`) or `partial`ized

### Summary

I'm conflicted. How do you solve problems where you need to do a non-trivial throw-away map?

Comment: If the transformation is non-trivial, don't bother trying to simplify it via with a list comprehension and instead strive for readability and ease-of-modification.

Comment: Make it a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Addressing just a part of the question: the redefinition of the inner  function each time the outer function is called is a non issue: the inner function is only actually parsed and compiled once (at module compilation time). Each time the outer function is called, all that is repeated is a function call to types.FunctionType passing the compiled bytecode as a parameter and getting a function object back - this should be relatively cheap compared to walking the actual list.

Comment: Given the number of considerations you list on the pros and cons, this is far too broad a question to answer.

Comment: It's just a matter of style. For me it depends on the case but I generally prefer nested functions if they are not reusable outside of the function. If they are than I promote them to an outer function or even a library if it's common enough.